# What did I do wrong in my function involving raising an exception?

Tags: python, exception

**The instructions:**
Write a function validate_input(string) which takes a command string in the format 'command arg1 arg2' and returns the pair ('command', [arg1, arg2]), where arg1 and arg2 have been converted to floats. If the command is not one of 'add', 'sub', 'mul', or 'div', it must raise InvalidCommand. If the arguments cannot be converted to floats, it must raise InvalidCommand.

Typical inputs and outputs:

validate_input('add 2 3') -> ('add' [2. , 3.])

validate_input('hahahaha 2 3') -> Raises InvalidCommand()

validate_input('add six 3') -> Raises InvalidCommand()

Here is my code:

```
class InvalidCommand(Exception):
    pass

def validate_input(string):
"""
validate_input(str) -> (str, [float])

If string is a valid command, return its name and arguments.
If string is not a valid command, raise InvalidCommand

Valid commands:
  add x y
  sub x y
  mul x y
  div x y

Arguments x and y must be convertable to float.

"""
    inlist = string.split(' ')
    commands = []
    strdigits = []
    floats = []
    output = []
    for x in inlist:
        if x.isdigit():
            strdigits.append(x)
        else:
            commands.append(x)
    for x in commands:
        try:
            x == 'add' or 'sub' or 'mul' or 'div'
            output.append(x)
        except ValueError:
            return InvalidCommand(ValueError)
    for x in strdigits:
        try:
            float(x)
            floats.append(float(x))
            output.append(floats)
        except ValueError:
            return InvalidCommand(ValueError)
    return tuple(output)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x == 'add' or x == 'sub' or x=='mul' or x=='div'`, or a better pythonic way, `x in ['add','mul','div','sub']`?
Try that for any invalid value,

Comment: Could you please clarify what your problem exactly is?

Comment: BTW your docstring needs to be indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line #37 (for loop), You are appending the value immediately from `floats`, which is causing it to append the list of float twice to the `output` variable. 
For input `mul 5 6`, it is returning `('mul', [5.0, 6.0], [5.0, 6.0])`, so the first thing you need to do it put `output.append(floats)` after the loop.

```
for x in strdigits:
    try:
        float(x)
        floats.append(float(x))
    except ValueError:
        return InvalidCommand(ValueError)
output.append(floats)
```

Secondly this is wrong way to do it,

```
x == 'add' or 'sub' or 'mul' or 'div'
```

Check these output from Python shell.

```
>>> x = 'fas'
>>> x == 'add' or 'sub' or 'mul' or 'div'
'sub'
>>> x in ['add','sub','mul','div']
False
>>> bool('sub')
True
```

I hope it's clear, so change your condition to

```
if x in ['add','sub','mul','div']:
    output.append(x)
else:
    raise InvalidCommand(ValueError)
```

to deal with invalid `command` value.

As Paul suggested in comments, use `raise Exception` to raise an exception.

Comment: Because an Exception is an Object, Python will let you `return` it.  But typically, in code like this, one uses a [`raise Exception` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=raise#grammar-token-raise_stmt) instead to trigger the Exception.   The requirement to use raise is also in the top of the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors,so I will address the question in the title: what are the errors with raising an exception ?

To raise an exception, use `raise ExceptionType(parameter)`, not `return`

Like this:

```
 class InvalidCommand(Exception):
     pass

 try:
      s = raw_input("Enter a number:")
      x = float(s)
 except ValueError:
      raise InvalidCommand(s+" is not a number")
```

Note that Custom exception types always need to be defined somewhere. Since `InvalidCommand` is a custom Exception type (not included in Python), there should be a class definition for `InvalidCommand` before using it.  This class definition could go near the top of the python program file, and only needs to appear once.

For more, see [Python docs -- errors and exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)