# This tutorial on raising exceptions. I cant figure it out?

Tags: python, exception

The instructions: Write a function validate_input(string) which takes a command string in the format 'command arg1 arg2' and returns the pair ('command', [arg1, arg2]), where arg1 and arg2 have been converted to floats. If the command is not one of 'add', 'sub', 'mul', or 'div', it must raise InvalidCommand. If the arguments cannot be converted to floats, it must raise InvalidCommand.

Typical inputs and outputs:

validate_input('add 2 3') -> ('add' [2. , 3.])

validate_input('hahahaha 2 3') -> Raises InvalidCommand()

validate_input('add six 3') -> Raises InvalidCommand()

Here is my code:

```
class InvalidCommand(Exception):
    pass

def validate_input(string):
"""
validate_input(str) -> (str, [float])

If string is a valid command, return its name and arguments.
If string is not a valid command, raise InvalidCommand

Valid commands:
  add x y
  sub x y
  mul x y
  div x y

Arguments x and y must be convertable to float.

"""
# your code here
    inlist = string.split(' ')
    commands = []
    strdigits = []
    floats = []
    output = []
    for x in inlist:
        if x.isdigit():
            strdigits.append(x)
        else:
            commands.append(x)
    for x in commands:
        try:
            x == 'add' or x == 'sub' or x == 'mul' or x == 'div'
            output.append(x)
        except ValueError:
            raise InvalidCommand(ValueError)
    for x in strdigits:
        try:
            float(x)
            floats.append(float(x))
        except ValueError:
             raise InvalidCommand(ValueError)
    output.append(floats)
    return tuple(output)
```

When I test it on the values where it is supposed to raise InvalidCommand(), It tells me "Your code must raise InvalidCommand(). But my code does. I checked for typos and there are not any. So did I do the whole raising statement wrong? Please show me how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: You only raise InvalidCommand if you encounter a ValueError. But there is nothing in that code that could possibly raise a ValueError.

Comment: You should probably have made this an edit to [your existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32294214/4014959). BTW, your docstring still needs indenting... :)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
x == 'add' or x == 'sub' or x == 'mul' or x == 'div'
```

does nothing. It does not actually do anything with the result of your test, certainly it does not raise `ValueError`.

What you need is something like this:

```
if x.lower in ('add', 'sub', 'mul', 'div'):
    output.append(x)
else:
    raise InvalidCommand('unknown command: {}'.format(x))
```

Your code works for the numeric arguments because `float()` can raise `ValueError` if it is given a string that can not be converted to a float:

```
>>> float('abcd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: abcd
```

Also, why you are passing `ValueError` as an argument to your custom exception? You might like to pass an error string that describes the nature of the error, e.g.

```
raise(InvalidCommand('arguments must be numeric: {}'.format(x))
```

or, you can pilfer `ValueError`'s message:

```
    try:
        float(x)
        floats.append(float(x))
    except ValueError as exc:
         raise InvalidCommand(exc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be.

```
class InvalidCommand(Exception):
    pass

def validate_input(datastr):
    """
    validate_input(str) -> (str, [float])

    If string is a valid command, return its name and arguments.
    If string is not a valid command, raise InvalidCommand

    Valid commands:
    add x y
    sub x y
    mul x y
    div x y

    Arguments x and y must be convertable to float.

    """

    inlist = datastr.split()
    if len(inlist) != 3:
        raise InvalidCommand('Bad command length: ' + str(len(inlist)))

    x = inlist[0]
    if x in ('add', 'sub', 'mul', 'div'):
        cmd = x
    else:
        raise InvalidCommand('Bad command verb: ' + x)

    floats = []
    for x in inlist[1:]:
        try:
            floats.append(float(x))
        except ValueError:
             raise InvalidCommand('Bad command arg: ' + x)

    return cmd, floats

#Test

data = [
    'add 1 2',
    'sub 3.0 2.0',
    'mul 4.5 1.5',
    'div 8 4',
    'add 1 2 3',
    'fred 2 3',
    'add a b',
    'sub 1 c',
]

for s in data:
    try:
        print(validate_input(s))
    except InvalidCommand as e:
        print(repr(s), e)
```

**output**

```
('add', [1.0, 2.0])
('sub', [3.0, 2.0])
('mul', [4.5, 1.5])
('div', [8.0, 4.0])
'add 1 2 3' Bad command length: 4
'fred 2 3' Bad command verb: fred
'add a b' Bad command arg: a
'sub 1 c' Bad command arg: c
```

I've changed the parameter of the `validate_input` function because `string` is the name of a standard Python module, so it can be confusing to use it for a simple variable name. And if you want to use that module then shadowing its name like that can lead to annoying bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same question for my uni subject csse1001. What I did was this:

```
# your code here
lst = string.split(' ')
commands = ['add', 'sub', 'mul', 'div']
if lst[0] not in commands:
    raise InvalidCommand()
if len(lst) != 3:
    raise InvalidCommand()
try:
    arg1 = float(lst[1])
    arg2 = float(lst[2])
    return(lst[0], [arg1, arg2])
except ValueError:
    raise InvalidCommand()
```

This worked for me.